# Filter ListViewItems using if statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I am trying to create a simple filter using a "Search" `TextBox` and `Button`, which simply filters items in `ListView` according to user input.

I made it work using following code:

```
If (item.SubItems(1).Text.Contains(txtSearch1.Text.ToLower) = False AndAlso
    item.SubItems(1).Text.Contains(txtSearch1.Text.ToUpper) = False) Then

    ListViewItems.Items.Remove(item)
End If
```

The code checks if the `ListViewItem` contains the string user is searching for, and if it doesn't, it removes the items, leaving only those who match with searched string.

The problem is, when a search string exactly matched with the `ListViewItem`, the item still gets removed.

For example: there are two items: `Item1`, `Item2` 

If user searches for "1", `item2` will be removed from the list. 
However, if user searches for "item1", both items get removed.

How do i get it work?

Comment: is there a reason your checking `SubItems(1)` both times? would this work better in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The exact match gets removed because of your `AndAlso` operation. It will not match both the `ToLower` and '`ToUpper` copies of the text so your condition will never succeed. You can change the condition to an `OrElse` so that it returns true if either one of them is true.

**Update**

To explain further using the examples you gave, by searching for 1, the correct behavior is exhibited because "1" has no case so it is the same in the upper and lower case copies of your search string. However, the moment an alphabetic character is included the search will fail because no string will match both "item2" and "ITEM2" unless you are using `Option Compare Text`

Answer (score 0):

I found (or just developed) the solution. 
I used only a single condition:

```
 If item.SubItems(1).Text.ToUpper.Contains(txtSearch1.Text.ToUpper) = False Then
    ListViewItems.Items.Remove(item)
End If
```

The problem was because of case of the input and listviewitem text, converting both of them to uppercase solved the issue. 
Thank anyways!